# EF code first existing database - IdentityUser table issue

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an issue with custom users.
I have a table called **Profiles** which I use for my users table (it wouldn't let me use Users, but that is a different issue!) and I created my dbcontext like this:

```
public partial class SkipstoneContext : IdentityDbContext<Profile>
{
    static SkipstoneContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SkipstoneContext>(null); // Existing data, do nothing
    }

    public SkipstoneContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    // ...
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(model => model.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(model => model.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(model => new { model.RoleId, model.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserSecret>().HasKey<string>(model => model.UserName);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have no had to create a **DbSet** for **Profile** because that is set in the inherited **IdentityDbContext** class

My profile class looks like this:

```
public partial class Profile : IdentityUser
{
    public Profile()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public string CompanyId { get; set; }        
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

When I run my project I get an error stating

> Invalid object name 'dbo.IdentityUsers'.

If I rename my table to **IdentityUsers** and run the project again I get an error stating

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Profiles'.

And that is what is confusing. It looks like EF is looking for 2 tables for the Users and not just the one.

Can anyone explain to me why?

**Update 1**

So to try and figure this out, I removed the inherited **IdentityDbContent** from **SkipstoneContext** and just inherited from **DbContext** instead.
The new context class looks like this:

```
public partial class SkipstoneContext : DbContext // : IdentityDbContext<Profile>
{
    static SkipstoneContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SkipstoneContext>(null); // Exsting database, do nothing
    }

    public SkipstoneContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    // ...
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ...
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProfileMap());
        /// ...
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(model => model.UserId);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(model => model.Id);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(model => new { model.RoleId, model.UserId });
        //modelBuilder.Entity<UserSecret>().HasKey<string>(model => model.UserName);
    }
}
```

I also commented out my bindings for **IdentityUserLogin**, **IdentityRole**, **IdentityUserRole** and **UserSecret** and this is when it started working.

Here is a look at **IdentityUserLogin**:

```
public class IdentityUserLogin
{
    public IdentityUserLogin();

    public virtual string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

It has a **IdentityUser** property and I think that is what is causing my issue. I know **Profile** inherits **IdentityUser** but for some reason it seems to think it is in another table.

So, my next task is to create a custom UserLogin and see if I can get EF to use that instread of **IdentityUserLogin**

Comment: Do you have a `DbSet` for `Profile` and `IdentityUser`?

Comment: no, that is what I am saying. IdentityDbContext should take care of my user table (I assume it would happily use Profiles as my User class is called Profile) but it seems to fall over for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. It was due to my mapping. I had my **Profile** mapping class which looked like this:

```
public class ProfileMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Profile>
{
    public IdentityUserMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.CompanyId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.CreatedById)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedById)
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Forename)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Surname)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.Email)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.CredentialId)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Property(t => t.PasswordHash)
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.SecurityStamp)
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.Discriminator)
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Profiles");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyId).HasColumnName("CompanyId");
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedById).HasColumnName("CreatedById");
        this.Property(t => t.ModifiedById).HasColumnName("ModifiedById");
        this.Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        this.Property(t => t.DateModified).HasColumnName("DateModified");
        this.Property(t => t.LastLoginDate).HasColumnName("LastLoginDate");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        this.Property(t => t.Forename).HasColumnName("Forename");
        this.Property(t => t.Surname).HasColumnName("Surname");
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(t => t.JobTitle).HasColumnName("JobTitle");
        this.Property(t => t.Telephone).HasColumnName("Telephone");
        this.Property(t => t.Mobile).HasColumnName("Mobile");
        this.Property(t => t.Photo).HasColumnName("Photo");
        this.Property(t => t.LinkedIn).HasColumnName("LinkedIn");
        this.Property(t => t.Twitter).HasColumnName("Twitter");
        this.Property(t => t.Facebook).HasColumnName("Facebook");
        this.Property(t => t.Google).HasColumnName("Google");
        this.Property(t => t.Bio).HasColumnName("Bio");
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyName).HasColumnName("CompanyName");
        this.Property(t => t.CredentialId).HasColumnName("CredentialId");
        this.Property(t => t.IsLockedOut).HasColumnName("IsLockedOut");
        this.Property(t => t.IsApproved).HasColumnName("IsApproved");
        this.Property(t => t.CanEditOwn).HasColumnName("CanEditOwn");
        this.Property(t => t.CanEdit).HasColumnName("CanEdit");
        this.Property(t => t.CanDownload).HasColumnName("CanDownload");
        this.Property(t => t.RequiresApproval).HasColumnName("RequiresApproval");
        this.Property(t => t.CanApprove).HasColumnName("CanApprove");
        this.Property(t => t.CanSync).HasColumnName("CanSync");
        this.Property(t => t.AgreedTerms).HasColumnName("AgreedTerms");
        this.Property(t => t.Deleted).HasColumnName("Deleted");
        this.Property(t => t.UserName).HasColumnName("UserName");
        this.Property(t => t.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PasswordHash");
        this.Property(t => t.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SecurityStamp");
        this.Property(t => t.Discriminator).HasColumnName("Discriminator");

        // Relationships
    }
}
```

As you can see, the line that states

> this.ToTable("Profiles");

that is the line that is causing the issue. Changing this solved my problem.